# Which article should be used in documenting arguments to a software function

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, software

If I have a function, e.g.,

```
function processDirectory(input, relPath, output) {}
```

And I want to document its parameters, shall I use `the` or `an` article? For example,

- *input* - the path to the source directory.
- *relPath* - the relative path inside of the source directory.
- *output* - the path in which to write the output.

I did some searching and e.g., [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/DefaultSocketFactory.html) they use `the port on which to listen.`.

What about throwing errors, such as "Please specify the path to the source directory", or "Please specify a path to a source directory", or "Please specify a path to the source directory". I reckon its the last one because it's `the` path to something we talk about later, but `a` source directory because we mention it for the first time? Although other developers would know which source directory we're talking about?

Answer (score 4):

I would say all of those options are correct. There can be a subtle difference in meaning, though:

> please specify **a** patch to the source directory: by using *a*, it is suggested that several different paths are possible, and that you need to provide one of those paths.
>
> please specify **the** patch to the source directory: there is only one path that is correct, so we refer to this as *the* path.

Now suppose that the programme requires a path to a specific source directory, and only one path can be provided, which will be used throughout the programme. Then you could use *the*.

But suppose the path can be to any image file on the user's computer, whichever the user chooses; this might point to using *a*.

Both can be true at the same time, so it probably wouldn't matter much which you chose.

Comment: but if I say `The path to a source file from which to read data.` don't I have to use `the source file` because I specify that it is the _file from which to read data_?

Comment: @user181157: I would say the same rules apply. Both *a source file* and *the* can be defended on that basis.